# How to order this list?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a list of applications. I need to order them in a specific way and install in that order.

Things to consider:

Some applications have as a requirement, another application.

Some applications need a reboot before install next application, we want this applications to stay at bottom of the list but some of them may require an application that doesn't need a reboot, so, it can happen that some application that doesn't have any requirement neither a reboot, goes after an application that needs a reboot.

An example:

```
P1 (Reboot)
P2 (Needs P3)
P3
P4 (Needs P1)
P5 (Reboot and needs P3)
P6 (Reboot)
P7
```

So, if we have the apps in that order:

```
P1 - P2 - P3 - P4 - P5 - P6 - P7
```

The correct order would be (for example):

```
P3 - P7 - P2 - P1 - P4 - P5 - P6
```

If theres a non reboot app that has as requirement an app that needs a reboot (like P4) would be better if they stay upper on list than the others reboot apps (P5 - P6)

Comment: To avoid having your question closed, you should consider toning down the requirement description and increasing the amount of text that *is actually asking a question*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [topological sorting](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Topological_sorting) algorithm.

Comment: i don't know if this considerate last statement with this sorting (put upper the ones without reebot that has as requirement one with reebot). Maybe joining two types of sorting would be the solution. Let me have a look, thank you

Comment: this is indeed a graph problem. IMO the apps should be first grouped by detecting connected components, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29